# Can't link two tables correctly

Tags: google-app-maker

First week with appmaker so baby steps here.

I'm trying to modify the people viewer template app to pull information on a list of people in my org.

I imported the list of peoples email addresses and a couple new items of information to the existing template (which works, I can see my new information in a table).

But when I try to link the new field to the localdata field, the relation does not offer me a choice on how to link them, and when I try to create a new table widget I see that it is trying to join them on ID (which is autogenerated in both tables) rather than email address. Attempts to move primary key to email are resisted/reverted instantly, as are attempts to just delete the id column.

Tips on where to go next with this?

Comment: Is one of your tables based on the directory model? If that is the case, then the tables cannot be linked because the directory model is read-only.

Comment: I wasn't able to link to directory, I linked it to the local data table, which yes, won't have the new info in it yet as written, but I can't get the link going yet regardless.